# Adding Plugin to Kibana Image in docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, kibana, elastalert

I am new to using docker and trying to add the elastalert plugin to my kibana image. I am using Kibana 7.0.1 and Elasticsearch 7.0.1 and trying to use the elastalert 7.0.1 kibana plugin from github. When I run `docker-compose up` using the below docker-compose.yml file it does seem to install the plugin, but it doesn't actually start up kibana. Am I missing another command? Thanks

```
services:
    ...
    kibana:
        image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.0.1
        ...
        command: ./bin/kibana-plugin install https://github.com/bitsensor/elastalert-kibana-plugin/releases/download/1.0.4/elastalert-kibana-plugin-1.0.4-7.0.1.zip
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So when you override command section you must remember to keep existing behavior which is set by image author.

So in you case you can actually install kibana plugin this way but you must also add Kibana start at the end of the command by using e.g. && to run process after plugin installation. So in your case it should be:

```
     command: sh -c './bin/kibana-plugin install https://github.com/bitsensor/elastalert-kibana-plugin/releases/download/1.0.4/elastalert-kibana-plugin-1.0.4-7.0.1.zip && exec /usr/local/bin/kibana-docker'
```

Comment: I would really appreciate if you could test that solution and accept my answer if it works for you

Comment: OK this looks like it should work but I get a "kibana exited with code 0" after the plugin installation completes. I am seeing that that is the right start command too for kibana

Comment: I'm sorry - you are right. I edited my answer to fix that :)